# How to get data from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to get data `businessName` under `Organization`, under the `payload` of `user`. Tried this but no luck

```
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

<Text mt={3} fontSize="20px" fontWeight="550" my="15px">
  Company
</Text>
<Box my="10px">
  <Input
    fontSize={14}
    placeholder={user && user.payload.Organization?.businessName}
  />
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the actual code used to select the state? See [mcve]. `Organization` appears to be an array, BTW.

Comment: OK just did @DrewReese

Comment: Had my answer resolved your question/issue? I see you had left a comment that has since been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`Organization` appears to be an array and all the `user` state appears to be nested in the `state.auth` root state property, so if you are attempting to select the 0th element's `businessName` property then I see the selector function looking something like the following:

```js
const businessName = useSelector(
  state => state.auth.user.payload.Organization[0].businessName
);
```

```js
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

<Text mt={3} fontSize="20px" fontWeight="550" my="15px">
  Company
</Text>
<Box my="10px">
  <Input
    fontSize={14}
    placeholder={user?.payload?.Organization?.[0]?.businessName}
  />
</Box>
```